# apps script doesn't read currency column correctly

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a column in spreadsheet that contains currency values like $10.15.  The script worked fine for several years but now the apps script changes the value to something like 10.1566666692.  I've checked the column's format is currency.

Logger.log on column that has currency $10.00 returns 10.0111233 which is displayed on report that the apps script generates.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot confirm your whole script, from `Logger.log on column that has currency $10.00 returns 10.0111233 which is displayed on report that the apps script generates.`, if you are using `getValues` and your Spreadsheet shows like `$10.00`, how about modifying it to `getDisplayValues`? But, if this was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.  Used:

```
balance = column[1].toLocaleString('en-US',{style:'currency',currency:'USD'}); 
//removed the float integer created by previous sum statement.
```